# Django running under Apache and mod_wsgi uses "virtual" file system?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Ok, I know this is strange, but after a day of searching, I couldn't find any answer to this problem.

I've got this system running since two years with Django under Apache with a classical mod_wsgi installation. An exact mirror of the web site is used for development and testing.

In order to speed up a query, I used the inbuilt Django cache, using a file backend. In development (inbuilt Django server) everything works fine and a file is created under `/var/tmp/django_cache`. Everything works also in production, but no file is created.

I was surprised, so I started experimenting and inserted a bunch of prints in the `django.core.cache` modules and followed the execution of the cache stuff. At a certain point I got to a `os.makedirs`, which doesn't create anything. I inserted a `open()`, created a file (absolute path) and nothing is created. Tried to read back from the nonexisting file and the content was there.

I'm really puzzled. It seems that somehow there is a sort of "virtual" filesystem, which works correctly but in parallel with the real thing. I'm using Django 1.11.11.

Who is doing the magic? Django, Apache, mod_wsgi? Something else?

Comment: No, there is no virtual file system. More likely the file is being created in another location, probably because the Apache user has a TMPDIR environment var set

Comment: @DanielRoseman How can an environment variable influence this `open("/tmp/test.tmp","w").write("test")`? Which can later be read. And the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, @DanielRoseman was right: "More likely the file is being created in another location". The reason it can impact on any filesystem operation is that it's a feature of `systemd` called [PrivateTmp](https://muras.eu/2017/12/06/apache-ubuntu-systemd-privatetmp/). From the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=):

> sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private /tmp and /var/tmp directories inside it that is not shared by processes outside of the namespace

In fact there is a bunch of folders in both `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` called something like `systemd-private-273bc022d82337529673d61c0673a579-apache2.service-oKiLBu`.

Somehow my `find` command never reached those folders. All created files are there in a very regular filesystem. Now I also understand why an Apache restart clears the Django cache. `systemd` deletes the process private tmp and creates a new one for the new process.

I found the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303327/329567